# Problem using Rouché's theorem (number of zeros)

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone please explain to me how to show that $z^5+z^4+5z^3-z^2+1$ has $3$ zeros inside the disk $|z|<1$?

The version of [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) that I use is where I need to show $|f-g|<|f|$ on $|z|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The term $5z^3$ looks quite 'big', right...? More precisely $5 > 1+1+1+1=4$.

Comment: I think I see now. So if $f(z)=5z^3$ and $g(z)=z^5+z^4+5z^3-z^2+1$, then $|f(z)-g(z)|\leq |z|^5+|z|^4+|z|^2+1=4<5=5|z|^3 \leq |f(z)|$.

Comment: What about if $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$ or $|z|=3$?

Comment: You have indeed got the first point. For $|z|=1/2$ the term $1$ is 'big' and for $|z|=3$ which term do you think is 'big'?

Comment: $z^5$? I think I've got the hang of it now. If I could ask you just one more question, if I took the same problem and only changed the $5z^3$ term to $4z^3$, (i.e. $z^5+z^4+4z^3-z^2+1$ for $|z|=1$) you wouldn't be able to let $f(z)=4z^3$ would you? What would you do then?

Comment: You may  show that $|z|=1+\epsilon$ works for $\epsilon>0$ small enough, then take the limit. But if you want the roots to be strictly smaller than one in abs value you would still need to show that there is no roots in that case on the circle (not too difficult here, though).